# Handling multiple queries with ibm watson text to speech service

Tags: java, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am working with ibm watson tts API but thing is that when i synthesize multiples sentences(one after another) there is a slight delay in between outputs but I would like it to be continuous (as if the seperate sentences were being said in one utterance). Is there anyway to do this? Or are there any other tts solutions that can help me with this?

This is the method that synthesizes the different utterances using the API :

```
public void sayUtterances() {
    String[] splitUtterance = {"this is", "the sentence I would",
                               "like to say in one utterance", "without pausing"};

    for(int i = 0; i < splitUtterance.length; i++) {
        textToSpeechService.synthesize(splitUtterance[i], Voice.EN_ALLISON);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the service in parallel and asynchronously. You don't need to wait for the response for the 1st sentence before invoking the service for the 2nd sentence.

Comment: I have tried this, but when I execute them asynchronously with a Stream Player I still get a pause in between utterances and when I execute one utterance and execute another synchronized with another object two utterances speak at the same time rather than one after the other.

Comment: I am not saying play them asynchronously, I am saying synthesise the audio files asynchronously and in parallel, but play them in series..

ie. if there are five sentences, ask for all 5 to be synthesised in parallel. Wait for the 1st to return, and play it, when that finishes, wait for the 2nd to return (if it hasn't already) and play it, ....

Comment: Okay I am sorry I was able to do what you have said and I am able to synthesize incoming utterances while playing them. There is still a bit of delay in between utterances though, is there a way to shorten this delay a bit more?

Comment: How big a delay? One way might be to issue the async synthesise in reverse order. i.e. request the 5th, then the 4th etc, though still all in parallel, but play them in the correct sequence.

Comment: It is still about a second of delay. And how would I be able to synthesize the last but play the first? What I did was created a blockingqueue for the synthesized utterances and added them to it as they were synthesized and played what was added to the list. Maybe I took a wrong approach to it and that is what is causing my delay.

Comment: That should be fine, the one second delay may due to the media player switching from one audio file to the next. Not sure how you could speed that up.

Comment: Alright thank you so much, I really appreciate it! Would you be able to help me with my other question involving the speech recognition? If you do not mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

TTS generates small silence (~400ms) at the beginning and end of each synthesis. So if you play one after other you still get these silences between them. You should remove them manually by dropping 0 magnitude samples.

Also the service has rather large input limit, so you can simply generate multiple phrases at once by calling the service with "this is the sentence I would like to say in one utterance without pausing". The service is a streaming service so it will start producing audio as soon as possible and you can pass them directly to audio device without receiving complete response.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. How exactly would i approach "manually dropping 0 magnitude samples"? And also, the reason I have split the results is because I would like to be able to add to the sentence while the system is synthesizing and speaking at the same time that way I can make it seem as if it is all one utterance.